# Can not make generateChangeLog working in liquibase to export data from existing database

Tags: sqlite, data-migration, liquibase

I read some similar questions, but I still can not figure out how to export data or schemas from an exiting database using liquibase. The database i am using is sqlite, and I always got problem.

```
java -jar liquibase-1.9.3.jar --driver=org.sqlite.JDBC --classpath=lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar --changeLogFile=test.data  --url=jdbc:sqlite:test.db --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog
```

the error is: Migration Failed: no such column: 'DECIMAL_POINTS'

I just have a testing table with 2 fields:  ID (integer type), and name (VARCHAR type).

Can somebody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find more examples about using liquibase with sqlite database. So, I tested and figured out by myself, and commented below:
You need to pick up right jdbc engine for liquibase, when I changed sqlitejdbc engine from sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar to sqlitejdbc-v056.jar (http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/), it works. So it is important to pick up right one.